# how to align the td on top/bottom with css

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have the following table (it contains 2 tds, one with a form and the other with a div):

```
<tr>
  <td class='center-column'>
    <form>
      A Form
    </form>
  </td>
  <td class='right-column'>
    <div id='groupWrapper'>
       Some Stuff
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

When I make the screen smaller (using @media query) I wanted the two td's to be one on top of the other. I managed this successfully with writing in the css:

```
.center-column{
  display:inline;
}
.right-column{
  display:inline;
}
```

Question is: the right-column comes out on bottom. How do I CHANGE THE CSS so that it is on top and the center-column is on bottom? 
I need an answer with ONLY CHANGING THE CSS. (I tried to float them right/left but didn't work)

Thanks

Comment: Sample images should explain your problem better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use flex,

Give `flex-direction: column-reverse;` to `tr` to achieve this. Resize the window to see the effect.

```css
.center-column {
  flex: 1;
}
.right-column {
  flex: 1;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  tr {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class='center-column'>
      <form>
        A Form
      </form>
    </td>
    <td class='right-column'>
      <div id='groupWrapper'>
        Some Stuff
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Ben Glad I could help :)